# Cant document enum with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * \enum compare_str_stat
 * \brief String Comparison Member Function status.
 * 
 * \var no_match explanation 1
 * \var match explanation 2
 * \var partial_match explanation 3
 */
enum compare_str_stat {
    no_match,       //!< String is not found
    match,          //!< Match has been found
    partial_match   //!< partial part
};
```

I am using Doxygen 1.8.6 and for some reason doxygen is not documenting the enum anywhere.  I cannot even find a mention of it.  I am trying to link to it with no luck.

Thanks...

Comment: Your example works great on my version of doxygen (1.4.1). However I can not figure out how to have it work for fortran enum

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check your doxygen configuration: the Doxyfile
In Doxyfile, there is a tag:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
```

Check if you set it as NO.